# Using RTC Eclipse client with Eclipse for RCP/Plug-in Developers

Tags: eclipse, jazz

I want to use a RTC Eclipse Client with my Eclipse for RCP/Plug-in Developers. How can I do that? I tried to use the p2 install version of RTC Eclipse client 3.0.1 but when I use the Eclipse Update Manager, I get the following error:

> WST XML Core (2.0.2.v200802150100-787BE_4CYQCD-DaQMIfPd) requires
>   plug-in "com.ibm.icu (3.4.4)", or compatible.

I googled a lot but couldn't find an explanation for that. Any hints how to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the p2 repo for your Eclipse client. For Galileo it would be:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo
```

I have a hard time finding the p2 repository for each, but you can try the links from the [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release).